# How to order Ranger's beast to attack with TCoE?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, animal-companions

In the PHB there is the Ranger subclass "Beast Master" which gives the opportunity to have a beast companion, which obey all orders from the Ranger. The beast attacks only if the ranger gives that command in his/her action.

But in TCoE there is a phrase for the beast, which says:

> "It can move and use its reaction on its own, but the only action it takes is the Dodge action, unless you take a bonus action on your turn to command it to take another action. That action can be one in its stat block or some other action. You can also sacrifice one of your attacks when you take the Attack action to command the beast to take the Attack action."

It means that the ranger may use his/her bonus action also to command the beast to attack.
Which as I understand doesn't exclude the option of the original PHB defined one.
Am I right, or I missunderstood this?
Please can someone clarify me how can a ranger command his/her beast to attack targets with the TCoE variant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually excludes the option of the original PHB. In the description of the *Beast Master Companions* in the TCoE pg.61:

> The Beast Master in the *Player's Handbook* forms a mystical bond with an animal. As an **alternative**, a Beast Master can take the feature below to form a bond with a special primal beast **instead**.

Also in the description of the *Primal Companion* feature:

> 3rd-level Beast Master feature, **which replaces the Ranger's Companion feature**

Emphasis mine.

So the intention is that you either take the PHB feature or the Tasha's one.

That means that if you are using the TCoE Beast Master you can take your bonus action to command your beast to take an action of its stat block or some other action. You can also forgo one of yours attack when **you** take the attack action to command the beast to take the Attack action.

Comment: Primal companion allows you to command your beast with a bonus action to take an action "in it's statblock" which includes an action that makes an attack. Why would you forgo your attack for the attack action when you can just use your bonus action for the maul action (from Beast of the Land)?